# wazuh-kibana-app not running development server

Tags: localhost, kibana, web-development-server, wazuh

### i want to run a local development server for wazuh-kibana-app, so i can modify the application's ui .. but every time i try to run the development server using "npm start" i get an error with response :

```
**> wazuh@4.2.4 start
> plugin-helpers start

'plugin-helpers' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**
```

---

this whole response is vague for me.. what i'm i missing here ? what should be done or installed to run the development server with npm start ??
in other words "what exactly should i do to run wazuh-kibana-app on localhost on my pc"

Answer (score 0):

Joe
The Wazuh Kibana app uses de Kibana "plugin-helpers" that need to be built in order to create a build of the app.
You can find information on how to prepare your development environment and later, how to generate a build for the app after development is done [here](https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-kibana-app/wiki/Develop-new-features).

Don't hesitate to ask if you have further questions.